# Set the argument to a function in order to process it

Tags: php

So, I neet to set the argument to a function in order to convert it to a .mp3 file. Using this line : `$tts->setText($row['raspuns']);` doesn't happen anything but if i write `$tts->setText("Hello World!");` it works perfectly, which takes me to the conclusion that i have to find a correct code to make that tts get the text. Can anyone help me please?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bot
        </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="bot.php "method="post">
            <lable>You:<input type="text" name="intrebare"></lable>
            <input type="submit" name="introdu" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("robo") or die(mysql_error());

$intrebare=$_POST['intrebare'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dialog where intrebare = '$intrebare'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = $result;
?>

<?php
require "tts.php";
$tts = new TextToSpeech();
**$tts->setText($row['raspuns']);**
*//$tts->setText("Hello World!");*
$tts->saveToFile("voice.mp3");
$file='voice.mp3';
?>

<div id="history">
<?php       

    while (true == ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    echo "<b>The robot says: </b><br />";
    echo $row['raspuns'];
    echo "<embed src =\"$file\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Here's the tts.php file:

```
<?php
class TextToSpeech {
    public $mp3data;
    function __construct($text="") {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}");
        }
    }

    function setText($text) {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}");
            return  $this->mp3data;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function saveToFile($filename) {
        $filename = trim($filename);
        if(!empty($filename)) {
            return file_put_contents($filename,$this->mp3data);
        } else { return false; }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Look Daniel, you need to mark your questions as answered! Now you got three questions that all has good answers here but without any mark. If you don't then people will stop helping you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the row from your result

If you want your code to work where your tts class calls are, change

```
$row = $result;
```

To

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Note you have a code block below that redefines the $row array.

Also note mysql_* functions are deprecated, use PDO or mysqli_ functions instead. Your current code is wide open to sql injects!

Comment: Ok. Are your query getting any result or more than one row? (mysql_fetch_row would require 1 row or you need to loop through the results with mysql_fetch_array() as you do further down.

Comment: And did you then uncomment the line $tts->setText($row['raspuns']); ?

Comment: Note you could then take away the while loop completely.